# Windows 10 Mobile App Extended Execution keeps getting denied

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to use Extended Execution on my Windows 10 UWP app for the purpose of location tracking. There are many examples of this online. I am basically using this common block of code.

```
using (var session = new ExtendedExecutionSession())
{
    session.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.LocationTracking;
    session.Description = "Tracking your location";
    session.Revoked += NewSession_Revoked;
    var result = await session.RequestExtensionAsync();

    switch (result)
    {
        case ExtendedExecutionResult.Allowed:
            await StartLocationTrackingAsync();
            break;
        default:
            case ExtendedExecutionResult.Denied:
            //Notify user or log this.
            break;
    }
}
```

This block of code is executed in the Suspending event handler for my app, like this:

```
public Scenario1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Application.Current.Suspending += Current_Suspending;
}

private async void Current_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    //Do my extended execution request here.
}
```

The first issue I had was I could not get that event to even fire but I read on SO that VS will not suspend your app while debugging. So, I forced it to suspend using the Lifecycle events drop down in VS. Now, I get the Suspending event to raise each time, which is good.

However, when I request the extended execution session, it is denied every single time. I have tried on the emulator and on my physical W10 Mobile device, multiple times each and every time, it is denied.

Why is this? How can I get it to be allowed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have already declared **Location** in the app manifest, you will have to *run the code in the foreground*, which means it will work in your `MainPage_Loaded` callback but **not** in the suspended state.

> A location tracking extended execution session can run as long as
>   needed. However, there can only be one such session running per
>   device. A location tracking extended execution session can only be
>   requested in the foreground, and the app must be in the Running state.
>   This ensures that the user is aware that the app has initiated an
>   extended location tracking session.

To run this in the background, see this -

> It is still possible to use the
>   GeoLocator while the app is in the background by using a background
>   task, or an app service, without requesting a location tracking
>   extended execution session.

You use `LocationTracking` extended execution when you -

> Specify ExtendedExecutionReason.LocationTracking when you create an
>   ExtendedExecutionSession if your app needs to regularly log the
>   location from the GeoLocator. Apps for fitness tracking and navigation
>   that need to regularly monitor the user's location and should use this
>   reason.

Here is the [full article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) on this.

Comment: thank you for the response. I had read the article you gave a link to but that and all the other stuff I read does not explain what you did, which is where to request the Extended Session from. I moved it as you suggested and IT WORKED! It is now Allowed. However, new problem, it is allowed so my StartLocationTrackingAsync method is called and all is good while it is in the foreground. However, when I suspend the app, everything stops working. I stop getting my OnPositionChanged events from the GeoLocator. When I resume, it starts working again. Did I miss another step in setup?

Comment: Extended execution location tracking isn't designed for running it in the background but regularly interacting with geo locator in the foreground. If you want bg execution, you will need to use either a bg task or an app service.

Comment: Okay, understood. But can you please answer one more question? I have the GeoLocation Position Changed event handler raising not on time interval, but rather on distance and it is set to 100 meters. I need the event to raise this often because I am using geo fencing. I thought I read that background tasks would only fire x number of minutes which is far too long for me. Is that true? Ideally, I have an event handler that raises like I do in the foreground. With a bg, I understand I will have to poll the location. Can I do it in seconds with one of the approaches?

Comment: I just read that background tasks are only run every 15 minutes, so this is no good.

Comment: Geofencing is location based, not time based. You don't want to do stuff too often when the location hasn't been changed. Also can you please ask a new question on this?